# Only if selection changes from option X to arbitrary option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do an ajax call after this condition: 
If my selection changes from option X to an arbitrary other option. 
I probably need to catch first the selected option (what would be X). The ajax call can be ignored for now but for testing purposes a console.log("Yes it works") would be sufficient.

Example code:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>X</option>
    <option>Y</option>
    <option>Z</option>
    <option>A</option>
</select>
```

I tried something like this:

```
$(function() {
  var curr = $('#mySelect option:selected');
  if (curr.val() === "X") {
    curr.change()(function{
      console.log("It works!");
    )}

  }

})
```

But this does not work of course.

Comment: Are you trying to determine if an option *other than* `X` was selected, or specifically when the selection change from `X` to something else?

Comment: I'm confused as part of the question says changing from X to other things, and then later the question talks about changing to X

Comment: But in any case, that's not valid syntax for a change event binding.  `curr.on('change', function)` or `curr.change(function)`

Comment: Only if selection changes from X to Y|Z|A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to keep track of what the previous value was.

```js
$(function(){
  const $select = $('#mySelect');
  let previousValue = $select.val();
  
  $select.on('change', e => {
    if (previousValue === 'X') {
      console.log('New value is', $select.val());
    }
    
    previousValue = $select.val();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>X</option>
    <option>Y</option>
    <option>Z</option>
    <option>A</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the comments under the question it appears your goal is to fire the AJAX request when the selection specifically changes away from the `X` value.

To achieve that you need to know what the previous value is when the `change` event occurs. This can be achieved by storing the value in a `data` attribute on the element which is updated on load and after each `change`. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  var $curr = $('#mySelect')
  $curr.on('change', function () {
    if ($curr.data('prevValue') == 'X') {
      console.log('Make your AJAX request here...');      
    }
    
    $curr.data('prevValue', $curr.val());
  }).trigger('change');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>X</option>
  <option>Y</option>
  <option>Z</option>
  <option>A</option>
</select>
```